# fill in numpy array without looping though all indices

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use a high-dimensional numpy array to store the norms of weighted sums of matrices.
For example:

```py
 mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4 = np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3)

 res = np.empty((8, 7, 6, 5))

 for i in range(8):
    for j in range(7):
        for p in range(6):
            for q in range(5):
                 res[i, j, p, q] = np.linalg.norm(i * mat1 + j * mat2 + p * mat3 + q * mat4)
```

I would like to ask that are there any methods to avoid this nested loop?

Comment: Were you helped by either of the answers provided thus far?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Here's one way you can do it, via adding axes with `None` (equivalent to `np.newaxis`):

```py
def weighted_norms(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4):
    P = mat1 * np.arange(8)[:, None, None]
    Q = mat2 * np.arange(7)[:, None, None]
    R = mat3 * np.arange(6)[:, None, None]
    S = mat4 * np.arange(5)[:, None, None]
    
    summation = S + R[:, None] + Q[:, None, None] + P[:, None, None, None]
    return np.linalg.norm(summation, axis=(4, 5))
```

### Veracity and a simple benchmark

```py
In [6]: output = weighted_norms(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)

In [7]: np.allclose(output, res)
Out[7]: True

In [8]: %timeit weighted_norms(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)
71.3 µs ± 446 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

### Explanation

By adding two new axes to the `np.arange` objects, you can force the broadcasting you want, producing `0 * mat1, 1 * mat1, 2 * mat1 ...`.

The real tricky bit is then constructing the `(8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 3)` array (which is the shape before evaluating the norm which collapses the last two dimensions).

Notice that the `summation` of all the weighted 3D arrays starts with the last array, `S`, and progressively adds more weighted 3D arrays. The way it does this is by adding a new axis to broadcast over at each step.

For example, the shape of `S` is `(5, 3, 3)` and in order to correctly add `R` you need to insert a new axis. So the shape of `R` goes from `(6, 3, 3)` to `(6, 1, 3, 3)`. This second dimension of size `1` is what allows us to broadcast the sum of `S` over `R` such that each array in the 3D `S` is added to each array in `R` (that's one level of nested loop).

Then we need to add `Q` (for every array in `Q`, for every array in `R`, for every array in `S`), so we need to insert two new axes turning `Q` from `(7, 3, 3)` to `(7, 1, 1, 3, 3)`.

Finally, `P` goes from `(8, 3, 3)` to `(8, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3)`.

It may help to "visualize" this by overlaying the shapes:

```py
            (5, 3, 3)  <-  S
             :
+        (6, 1, 3, 3)  <-  R[:, None]
---------------------
         (6, 5, 3, 3)
          :  :
+     (7, 1, 1, 3, 3)  <-  Q[:, None, None]
---------------------
      (7, 6, 5, 3, 3)
       :  :  :
+  (8, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3)  <-  P[:, None, None, None]
---------------------
   (8, 7, 6, 5, 3, 3)
```

### Generalizing

Here's a generalized version using a helper function for adding axes just to clean up the code a little:

```py
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np


def add_axes(x: np.ndarray, n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Inserts `n` number of new axes into `x` from axis 1 onward.
    e.g., for `x.shape == (3, 3)`, `add_axes(x, 2) -> (3, 1, 1, 3)`
    """
    return np.expand_dims(x, axis=(*range(1, n + 1),))


def weighted_norms(arrs: Tuple[np.ndarray], weights: Tuple[int]) -> np.ndarray:
    if len(arrs) != len(weights):
        raise ValueError("Number of arrays must match number of weights")
    summation = np.empty((weights[-1], *arrs[-1].shape))
    for i, (x, w) in enumerate(zip(arrs[::-1], weights[::-1])):
        summation = summation + add_axes(x * add_axes(np.arange(w), 2), i)
    return np.linalg.norm(summation, axis=(-1, -2))
```

Usage:

```py
In [10]: arrs = (mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)

In [11]: weights = (8, 7, 6, 5)

In [12]: output = weighted_norms(arrs, weights)

In [13]: np.allclose(output, res)
Out[13]: True

In [14]: %timeit weighted_norms(arrs, weights)
109 µs ± 3.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```